# Avoiding recreating Gson instances for Room Type Converters

Tags: java, android, architecture, gson, android-room

Alternatively, the question could be titled: Avoiding using a Singleton Util as a `Gson` wrapper.

In my Android project that uses Room for persistence, I have quite a few entities where certain columns are non-primitive types. After looking around for a bit, I found that using `TypeConverter` along with `Gson` to convert the non-primitive types to and from strings is a decent solution.

Now, the class which houses the `TypeConverter`s looks like this:

```
class Converters {
    ...

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long fromDate(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long timestamp) {
        return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(timestamp);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromAddressData(AddressData addressData) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(AddressData.class, new AddressDataAdapter())
                .create();
        return gson.toJson(addressData);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static AddressData toAddressData(String addressDataString) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(AddressData.class, new AddressDataAdapter())
                .create();
        return gson.fromJson(addressDataString, AddressData.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromUserData(UserData userData) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(userData);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static UserData toUserData(String userDataString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(userDataString, UserData.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromCollectionData(CollectionData data) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(CollectionData.class, new CollectionDataAdapter())
                .create();
        return gson.toJson(data, CollectionData.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static CollectionData toCollectionData(String dataString) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(CollectionData.class, new CollectionDataAdapter())
                .create();
        return gson.fromJson(dataString, CollectionData.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromRequestNoteList(List<RequestNote> noteList) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(noteList, RequestNote.LIST_TYPE);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<RequestNote> toRequestNoteList(String noteListString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(noteListString, RequestNote.LIST_TYPE);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromRequestState(RequestState requestState) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(requestState);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static RequestState toRequestState(String requestStateString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(requestStateString, RequestState.class);
    }

    ...
}
```

My question is; is it okay and acceptable to have a setup like this? If I have many rows which are fetched using a Room DAO, will each row call an associated `TypeConverter`? Doesn't that add quite a bit of overhead because of creating a `Gson` instance each time?

Now, I do not like this setup. It feels like unnecessary instantiation. To avoid it, I ended up with a Singleton `Gson` wrapper. I can access it from anywhere and it's more or less a util.

```
public class DeSerializer {
    //Added formatters; please ignore the ignorance towards proper localization
    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    private static final SimpleDateFormat TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATETIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM, yyyy, hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

    private static final DecimalFormat DISTANCE_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("#.00 km");

    //Singleton gson instance
    private static Gson mGson;

    public static Gson gson() {
        if(mGson == null) {
            synchronized (DeSerializer.class) {
                if(mGson == null) {
                    mGson = new GsonBuilder()
                            .registerTypeAdapter(AddressData.class, new AddressDataAdapter())
                            .registerTypeAdapter(ImageData.class, new ImageDataAdapter())
                            .registerTypeAdapter(CollectionData.class, new CollectionDataAdapter())
                            .create();
                }
            }
        }

        return mGson;
    }

    //Gson wrapper methods
    public static String toJson(Object src) {
        return gson().toJson(src);
    }

    public static String toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc) {
        return gson().toJson(src, typeOfSrc);
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
        return gson().fromJson(json, classOfT);
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
        return gson().fromJson(json, typeOfT);
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(String json, TypeToken<T> typeTokenOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
        return fromJson(json, typeTokenOfT.getType());
    }

    //Additional utility; please ignore the blurred boundaries of single responsibility
    public static JsonObject jsonWebTokenPayload(String token) {
        String[] parts = token.split("\\.");
        String json = new String(Base64.decode(parts[1], Base64.URL_SAFE));
        return gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> T getParcelable(Bundle data, String key, ClassLoader loader) {
        data.setClassLoader(loader);
        return data.getParcelable(key);
    }

    public static String dateString(Date date) {
        return DATE_FORMAT.format(date);
    }

    public static String timeString(Date date) {
        return TIME_FORMAT.format(date);
    }

    public static String datetimeString(Date date) {
        return DATETIME_FORMAT.format(date);
    }

    public static String distanceString(Number distance) {
        return DISTANCE_FORMAT.format((double) distance / 1000);
    }
}
```

Then, in the `Converters` class, I can use `DeSerializer` instead of having to instantiate a relevant `Gson` instance each time.

Except Singletons are supposedly evil. When I say supposedly, I mean that due to my lack of understanding, I am unable to see why this setup is bad. I mean, I know it's not the best solution, or even decent, but I'm unable to think of something else without using singleton as a crutch.

`DeSerializer` is not a proper dependency, and, in my ignorance, I want to say that testability is not an issue since I can't see a case where I'd want to fake or stub `DeSerializer`.

So, the second part of my question is; is this setup acceptable? Or does it break all the rules of clean architecture?

What is recommended in this case, where I can't inject a dependency into `Converters` but I also don't want to keep having to recreate `Gson` instances?

Comment: Anything against a static field inside `Converters`? `private final static Gson gson = new Gson()`? You can even make it thread safe if needed.

Comment: @Fred Initially, before posting the question, I did consider that approach and was happy with it until it struck me that this is no different than using the singleton. But, now that you've mentioned it, I think it still is the better way to go about it, especially considering how the Room `TypeConverter`s are all static.

Comment: Yes you are right. It just less complexity than a Singleton. To be honest I don't see any other way. One could consider passing it as a parameter, but I assume room calls these methods automatically and that they have to follow a specific signature.